# How to get the link value that written? - JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, parameters, request

I want to get a value from the link that user has write.
For example i want to go to page `pageone.jsp?x=abc` , then **how to get variable "x"** (that written in url ?x=abc, and then prinln(x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use request.getParameterNames()**

```
 Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
      out.println("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
      String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
      if (paramValues.length == 1) {
        String paramValue = paramValues[0];
        if (paramValue.length() == 0)
          out.print("<I>No Value</I>");
        else
          out.print(paramValue);
      } else {
        out.println("<UL>");
        for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
          out.println("<LI>" + paramValues[i]);
        }
        out.println("</UL>");
      }
    }
```

refr http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Form-Data.html